# How to model Firebase database for write only, but don't read, for logging?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

How can we model a Firebase database so that anonymous users can write data, but no once can read it?

Also no one, including the anonymous user, should be allowed to overwrite/edit data.

The goal is to have a data model similar to logging, so that we can use cloud functions to process the data later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you store the log nodes under `/log/$logid`:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "log": {
      "$logid": {
        ".write": "!data.exists()",
        ".read": false,
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I highly recommend studying the [Firebase documentation on security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/). A few hours spent there, will save you much time and many question going forward.